# Java Netbeans, libraries not being packaged into jar file on build

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, build, libraries

I am using netbeans and have this in my build.xml file (under Project > Build.xml)

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
<property name="store.jar.name" value="MyProjectName"/>
<property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
<property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
<echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
<delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

<jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>

<zip destfile="${store.jar}">
    <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
</zip>

<delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
```

Supposedly what this should do is package the 3 libraries i have into my jar file so that when the jar is run it has its dependencies with it.

My folder system looks like this:

Project / dist / lib /

- commons-lang3-3-7.jar
- commons-text-1.1.jar
- jsoup-1.10.3.jar

But when i click "Clean and Build" in netbeans it does not package the libraries into the jar, instead it seems to be ignoring the code that i have put in the build.xml file.

Is there some button that i need to click in order to get it to use my build configuration?

Comment: So, unless something has changed in the last few years, you can't reference Jars from within Jars by default.  One solution would be to use something like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net) which would do what you want, but it increases the complexity of launching your App slightly.  Other solution is to generate a "fat jar", where all the classes from all the dependent Jars are Jar'ed into the one jar (note - this is not the same same as Jar'ing the dependent Jars)

Comment: Yes that is true, however i somehow was able to create a jar with the dependencies un-archived within it. But now i cannot find the button to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. In Netbeans it is possible to build the dependent libraries within the jar file.

Netbeans features a tool that automatically un-archives the dependent libraries and includes them in the jar (such as MyJar.jar|org\apache\commons...).

And it is actually very easy to do!

- First you need to click on the "Files" tab in the top left window which shows your project. Then you should be able to see all your files including the Build.xml (in which you have put your build code, such as that featured in the question above).
- Right click on the Build.xml file and select "Run Target"
- Then choose "Other Target" in the pop up menu
- Then select "package-for-store" in the further pop up menu

This will then build your jar file, with dependencies under /YourProject/store/

Comment: Just beware that "fat jars" have draw backs if they share resources with the same name

Comment: Is there any way to know if there is overlapping resources?

Comment: Let's just start with the fact that it's a very particular edge case, which I did trip across on some projects, which is why I investigated OneJar. The issue is, if one or more dependencies have the same named file, in the same named directory, when you produce a "Fat Jar", they will overwrite each other. In most cases, the chances are pretty slim you'd have this problem, but because I tend to use a "common" discovery system with my personal dependencies, it caused me issues. To answer your question, no, not easily.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind in case i notice any odd behavior, currently i am using very few classes and so probably won't have any problems but it is good to know about OneJar.